# Map network drive programmatically in C# on Windows 10

Tags: c#, network-programming

I followed the approache to map a network drive programmatically in the following link:
[Mapping Network Drive using C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90143/Mapping-Network-Drive-using-C)

The drive seems to be connected correctly because I can query directories and files within C#. BUT I do not see the drive on my computer.
My target is to map certain drives programmatically for my users.
I don'T want to use batch/cmd...
Is there maybe a problem with windows 10 or is this code just good for programming approaches.

Kind Regards

Use of code:

```
Utility.NetworkDrive.MapNetworkDrive("R", @"\\unc\path");
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("R:"); // got many nice directories...
Utility.NetworkDrive.DisconnectNetworkDrive("R", true);
```

Full Code:

```
namespace Utility
{
    public class NetworkDrive
    {
        private enum ResourceScope
        {
            RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 1,
            RESOURCE_GLOBALNET,
            RESOURCE_REMEMBERED,
            RESOURCE_RECENT,
            RESOURCE_CONTEXT
        }
        private enum ResourceType
        {
            RESOURCETYPE_ANY,
            RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
            RESOURCETYPE_PRINT,
            RESOURCETYPE_RESERVED
        }
        private enum ResourceUsage
        {
            RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_NOLOCALDEVICE = 0x00000004,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_SIBLING = 0x00000008,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED = 0x00000010
        }
        private enum ResourceDisplayType
        {
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NETWORK,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_ROOT,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHAREADMIN,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DIRECTORY,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_TREE,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NDSCONTAINER
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct NETRESOURCE
        {
            public ResourceScope oResourceScope;
            public ResourceType oResourceType;
            public ResourceDisplayType oDisplayType;
            public ResourceUsage oResourceUsage;
            public string sLocalName;
            public string sRemoteName;
            public string sComments;
            public string sProvider;
        }
        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetAddConnection2
            (ref NETRESOURCE oNetworkResource, string sPassword,
            string sUserName, int iFlags);

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2
            (string sLocalName, uint iFlags, int iForce);

        public static void MapNetworkDrive(string sDriveLetter, string sNetworkPath)
        {
            //Checks if the last character is \ as this causes error on mapping a drive.
            if (sNetworkPath.Substring(sNetworkPath.Length - 1, 1) == @"\")
            {
                sNetworkPath = sNetworkPath.Substring(0, sNetworkPath.Length - 1);
            }

            NETRESOURCE oNetworkResource = new NETRESOURCE()
            {
                oResourceType = ResourceType.RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
                sLocalName = sDriveLetter + ":",
                sRemoteName = sNetworkPath
            };

            //If Drive is already mapped disconnect the current 
            //mapping before adding the new mapping
            if (IsDriveMapped(sDriveLetter))
            {
                DisconnectNetworkDrive(sDriveLetter, true);
            }

            WNetAddConnection2(ref oNetworkResource, null, null, 0);
        }

        public static int DisconnectNetworkDrive(string sDriveLetter, bool bForceDisconnect)
        {
            if (bForceDisconnect)
            {
                return WNetCancelConnection2(sDriveLetter + ":", 0, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                return WNetCancelConnection2(sDriveLetter + ":", 0, 0);
            }
        }

        public static bool IsDriveMapped(string sDriveLetter)
        {
            string[] DriveList = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
            for (int i = 0; i < DriveList.Length; i++)
            {
                if (sDriveLetter + ":\\" == DriveList[i].ToString())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of process are you running this from?

Comment: I tried in VS Debug mode and started the compiled exe as well. All under my logged in user account.

Comment: Have you tried something along these lines? https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/242590-The-best-way-to-effect-quotnet-usequot-from-C

Comment: I visited exactly this site. I first tried to call net use... via process. The output said 'Successfully...' for adding and removing the connection. But I did not see the drive . Then I even created a batch file and called it via process.start, same result. Positive output, programstically access but unable to see the drive. Even if I type the drive into the explorers address bar: unable to find drive...

Comment: I am currently on my way into the office, I will provide code in an hour.

Comment: Alright, I fully lose my faith in Windows somewhen... after restarting my laptop, all approached wirks well. I will post them as answers. Thanks you anyway :)

Comment: did you maybe run the program with uac (right click "run as administrator") when it didn't work?

Comment: It's cool that restart helped, but not for me - I have the same strange issue, looks like mapped drive exists virtually in VS framework, but nothing works and visible in Explorer. Any other ideas what can lead to such behavior and how can it be fixed?

Comment: @Mario Can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72979000/add-network-location-via-c-sharp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Resting my laptop seemed to fix whatever problem windows had.
All three approaches below are working like a charm. My favorite one is of course the C# "only" approach.

```cs
// Approach 1
Utility.NetworkDrive.MapNetworkDrive("R", @"\\unc\path");
var dirs1 = Directory.GetDirectories("R:");
Utility.NetworkDrive.DisconnectNetworkDrive("R", true);

// Approach 2
DoProcess("net", @"use R: \\unc\path");
var dirs2 = Directory.GetDirectories("R:");
DoProcess("net", "use /D R:");

// Approach 3
DoProcess("cmd", @"/c C:\local\path\to\batch\connect.cmd");
var dirs3 = Directory.GetDirectories("R:");
DoProcess("cmd", @"/c C:\local\path\to\batch\diconnect.cmd");

public static string DoProcess(string cmd, string argv)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = $" {argv}";
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.Dispose();

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'Utility' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2):

Mapped drives can be very confusing.  The issue is that they only appear for the "user" that created them.  This was hinted at in the question in the comments about UAC and Run as Administrator.

IF you "Run As" whoever, then the drives will only appear for that whoever.

If you are only worried about User vs Elevated user access, there is a registry key to enable this:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

EnableLinkedConnections

Please see this for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command

Answer (score -1):

If you are using @Mario's Approach 2 and want to keep the drive then remove the following line:

```
DoProcess("net", "use /D R:");
```