# I've got a problem with map network drive

Tags: c#

I'm trying map network drive in code of c#. I'm using ProcessStartInfo class, I've got a problem with whitespaces in attribute 'Arguments', I think so... 
Below is a piece of code...

```
    private void getMapDrive(string user, string pwd)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"/C net use P: \\server\foldername /user:"+user+" "+pwd;

            Process.Start(startInfo);

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            lblMessage.Content = err.Message;
        }


    }
```

Comment: You'll have to get this going with /K instead of /C.  So you can read the error message.  You won't get an exception when the command fails, use the Process.ExitCode to detect misery.  Prefer to make it reliable by calling the corresponding function instead, Google can show you when you query for "c# wnetaddconnection2".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map network drive programmatically in C# on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173970/map-network-drive-programmatically-in-c-sharp-on-windows-10)

Comment: Ok it works, but if someone types the wrong password, how to catch error message from CMD, for example if error will be: ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE

1326 (0x52E)

The user name or password is incorrect.